# Из-за чего ошибка в консоли?

Tags: javascript

Вот демка https://jsbin.com/kujeqefegi/edit?html,js,console,output
Есть простой html и скрипт, часть которого отвечает за добавление новых блоков, а часть за удаление:

```
// Добавлене блоков
var div = '';
var next_id = 3;
add_block.onclick = function() {
    next_id++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 's'+next_id;
    div.className = 'text block';
    var template = 'new - удали меня';
    div.innerHTML = template;
    main.appendChild(div);
};

//Удаление блоков
main.onclick = function() {
  var DelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.text.block');
  var DelButtonsArray = Array.from(DelButtons);
  DelButtonsArray.forEach(function(button){
      button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          document.getElementById(e.target.id).remove();
      })
  });
}
```

Да я знаю что метод .remove() не кроссбраузерный, вопрос сейчас в другом, после удаления в консоли появляется ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null at
>   HTMLDivElement.

Он пытается получить доступ к id который только что удалён что ли был? Как это предотвратить?

Comment: ты внутри одного клика `main.onclick` навешиваешь в цикле другие клики.. в итоге первый клик не срабатывает, второй удаляет один элемент, третий клик - пытается убить два элемента, и так по возрастающей.....если убрать `main.onclick = function() {` и последнюю скобку `}`  то будет работать ))) я правда пока не понял вообще для чего было сделано `main.onclick`

Comment: Если ты хочешь клик навесить на вновь создавшийся элемент, то в конце обработчика `add_block` можно написать `main.appendChild(div);
  
    document.getElementById(div.id).addEventListener('click', function(e) {        
        this.remove();
    });` .... но это самый быстрый вариант...

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский По поводу первого комментария: убрать main.onclick и скобку я пробовал, тогда первые блоки (которые существовали) будут удалться а новые нет https://jsfiddle.net/aur559bu/ ошибок в консоли при этом никаких нет

Comment: https://jsbin.com/foyuceluqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output  ...... на новые надо навешивать обработчики... а так ты после каждого добавления блока навешиваешь еще обработчики в цикле и они возрастают в прогрессии

Comment: на самом деле просто не нужен `document.getElementById(e.target.id)` - нужно заменить на `e.target`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский хмм спасибо...

Comment: @Grundy подскажи как ему лучше сделать, чтоб не повторяться в коде. у меня голова не варит. ...не забудь, что он в клике на блок в начале вешает обработчики  в цикле

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский так querySelectorAll возвращает коллекцию, а по ней надо бежать в цикле. Может и есть другой способ, но мне он не извечтен ))

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5dqoftjg/2/  что-то типа такого.. хотя надо еще бы прибраться..